# query is highly performant without an ORDER BY, slows to a crawl with an ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT n.id, n.member_id, n.content, n.created_at
FROM notes n
JOIN note_metadata nm ON n.id = nm.note_id
    AND nm.meta_key_id = 4 # Nature
    AND nm.meta_value = 'Cancellation'
#ORDER BY n.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Without the ORDER BY the query is very performant. Here's what the EXPLAIN looks like for that:

[image]

*With* the ORDER BY, however, the query slows down to a crawl. Here's what the EXPLAIN looks like for that:

[image]

Here's the CREATE TABLE for notes:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_public` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_archived` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `notes_type_id_foreign` (`type_id`),
  KEY `member_id` (`member_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `_notes_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `note_types` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21374344 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here's the CREATE TABLE for note_metadata:

```
CREATE TABLE `note_metadata` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `note_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meta_key_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meta_value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `note_metadata_meta_key_id_foreign` (`meta_key_id`),
  KEY `_note_metadata_note_id_foreign` (`note_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `_note_metadata_note_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`note_id`) REFERENCES `notes` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `note_metadata_meta_key_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`meta_key_id`) REFERENCES `note_meta_keys` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4098655 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Any idea how I can make the latter query - the one with the ORDER BY - as fast as the former? Do I need to add a new index or some such?

Comment: Does every entry in note have a corresponding record in note_metadata?

Comment: I suspect that `meta_key_id` can be replaced by `meta_key VARCHAR(..)` and get the table mapping key ids and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `meta_value` is defined as a `text` column, when defining a key you need to specifiy the prefix length. You should add the following composite index:

```
ALTER TABLE note_metadata
    ADD INDEX (meta_key_id, meta_value(20), note_id);
```

You should change the `ORDER BY` clause to `nm.note_id`, instead of `n.id`.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0rLuRDou).

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding the `(note_id,meta_key_id,meta_value(10))` index and drop `_note_metadata_note_id_foreign` index .

Use,

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES note_metadata WRITE;
alter table `note_metadata` 
add index note_mkey_mval(note_id,meta_key_id,meta_value(10)),
drop index `_note_metadata_note_id_foreign`;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

[Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20can%20use%20multiple%2Dcolumn,three%20columns%2C%20and%20so%20on.)

[The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#idm46090611118768)

Comment: I doubt if any of the LOCK/UNLOCK/COMMIT are needed.

Comment: @RickJames you have asked me once about why I am using lock/commit/unlock. Sometimes it throws an error duplicate .... if I use alter table only as described in point 4 on [Online DDL Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-limitations.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20limitations%20apply%20to,NULL%20constraints%20on%20the%20table.) . I decided to make a 'work practice'

Comment: Hmmm...  That sounds like something that should be escalated to a bug report and/or be documented in other places.

Answer (score -1):

Creating an index might help.

```
 CREATE INDEX notes_id_idx ON notes(id DESC);
```

Comment: `notes.id` is already PK.

Comment: And the Optimizer is willing to do all `DESC` even when the `INDEX` is all `ASC`.  It simply scans the index in reverse order.